# Shutdown hook for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby

I'd like to have some cleanup code run when Rails is shutting down - is that possible?  My situation is that I have a few threads in the background (I'm using jruby and calling into java) that live for the life of the process and I need to let them know to shut themselves down

Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Probably should just use the Ruby exit handler, which is a Kernel method:

```
$ irb
>> at_exit do
?>   puts 'bye...'
>> end
=> #<Proc:0xb79a87e4@(irb):1>
>> exit
bye...
$
```

Comment: As long as JRuby itself has a lifecycle corresponding to the underlying application server, then you can put it anywhere it will get run at least once. A good place would be to register the exit handler in whatever piece of Ruby code fires off those background threads in the first place.

Comment: (If it does get called more than once the exit handlers will run more than once, however, so don't call it 30,000 times. :-)

Comment: @Stuart: did you ever implement this?  if so, how did it go and where did you put it?

Comment: Thanks to DigitalRoss for the code hint and Radar for right file.

@efleming I implemented this after 10 years of giving the solution and 8 years of asking about it :-P

Answer (score 11):

Within the context of a Rails Application, the best place to put such a file is in `config/initializers`.  In my app, I needed to Flush the Redis/Sidekiq queue whenever the development or test environments shut down.  This works perfectly.

#### config/initializers/at_exit.rb

```
at_exit do
  begin
    puts 'Flushing Redis...'
    Redis.new.flushall
  rescue => e
    puts "There was an #{e.to_s} while flushing redis..."
  ensure
    puts 'Done Flushing Redis!'
  end
end unless Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you **must not use** `Signal.trap` because it does redefine what was set. There is a trick to call previous trap:

```rb
$prev_trap = Signal.trap("TERM") do
  $prev_trap&.call
  graceful_shutdown
end
```

However Rails initializators are executed before app server starts, e.g. Puma redefines most of the signal traps throwing away what was defined. **Therefore do not use this**, it might work maybe for webrick but not in production environmentální.

So the only reasonable option is what was already recommended by folks: `at_exit` in an initializer.