# How can I ensure an operation runs before Rails exits, without using `at_exit`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an operation that I need to execute in my rails application that before my Rails app dies. Is there a hook I can utilize in Rails for this? Something similar to `at_exit` I guess.

Comment: Duplicate of [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610573/shutdown-hook-for-rails). P.S. `at_exit` seems correct [With a little more info](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/06/are-we-abusing-at-exit/)

Comment: I would like to avoid `at_exit` because as I understand it, that can impact the exit status code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby itself supports two hooks, `BEGIN` and `END`, which are run at the start of a script and as the interpreter stops running it.

See "[What does Ruby's BEGIN do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050296/what-does-rubys-begin-do/14050393#14050393)" for more information.

The [`BEGIN`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000005) documentation says:

> Designates, via code block, code to be executed unconditionally before sequential execution of the program begins. Sometimes used to simulate forward references to methods.

```
puts times_3(gets.to_i)

BEGIN {
  def times_3(n)
    n * 3
  end
}
```

The [`END`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000006) documentations says:

> Designates, via code block, code to be executed just prior to program termination.

```
END { puts "Bye!" }
```

Comment: This will surprisingly execute prior to a defined finalizer.

Comment: As special language features, the existence of BEGIN seems less necessary than END. If you want code to run when your program starts up, you can just put the code inside a class. BEGIN is also awkward because it gets executed before any other code, so it can't call methods that you define.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so I am making no guarantees as to impact because I have not tested this at all but you could define your own hook e.g.

```
 ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(YOUR_RAILS_APP::Application, proc {puts "exiting now"})
```

Note this will execute after `at_exit` so the rails application server output will look like

```
Stopping ...
Exiting
exiting now
```

With Tin Man's solution included

```
 ObjectSpace.define_finalizer(YOUR_RAILS_APP::Application, proc {puts "exiting now"})
 END { puts "exiting again" }
```

Output is

```
 Stopping ...
 Exiting
 exiting again
 exiting now
```